# Fine-tune dialoGPT with a new dataset - loss below 1 and perplexity exploded

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, gpt-2

I am following the tutorial https://github.com/ncoop57/i-am-a-nerd/blob/master/_notebooks/2020-05-12-chatbot-part-1.ipynb on fine-tuning DialoGPT (GPT-2) with a new conversational dataset.

It was trained fine earlier, the perplexity was about 5, 6 and the resulting dialogue seemed normal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcSz3.png)Now, I am not sure if I touched somewhere...when I plotted the training loss, I found it went down to below 1 (about 0.25) and perplexity was over 300?